# MySQL 5.6 events are created disabled and they don't run

Tags: mysql, event

I am using the normal syntax to create an event, but they are created disabled and they never run:

```
create event p1 on schedule at now() on completion preserve enable do call proc1();
```

I added `enable` although it is default to solve this problem, but no good as well, and I need to preserve the event such that I can find it `show events` / `select * from information_scheme.events;`

I appreciate your help very much with any privileges required, configuration, or syntax to solve this problem.

Comment: "now()" has passed by the time it might be triggered.  Anyway, why have an event to run only once; why not simply do the 'call'?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify the interval

```
create event p1
    on schedule
    every week
    at now()
on completion preserve
enable do call proc1();
```

I have [***several examples of how to set up events***](https://dba.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3A877%20COMPLETION%20PRESERVE)

BTW make sure you enable the croning mechanism in my.cnf by adding this line

```
[mysqld]
event_scheduler = 'ON';
```

You don't have to reboot. Just run this

```
mysql> SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = 'ON';
```

As the last step, you can create the event.

Comment: Hi, Thank you very much, I just want to run it once, can I skip the interval.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-event.html

It seems optional,

Comment: The better approach for running an event once would be to leave out `ON COMPLETION PRESERVE`. That way, once the event is finished, it disabled.